# Why `CClientDC dc (this);` can't replace by `CClientDC dc = CClientDC(this);`

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am a newbie to MFC programming. These days I am using Jeff Prosise's book to learn MFC programming. I have encountered: `CClientDC dc (this);` and I have found a constructor function from the definition of CClientDC class : `CClientDC(CWnd* pWnd);` but if I replace `CClientDC dc (this);` with `CClientDC dc = CClientDC(this);`. the compiler told me this is a mistake. I can't understand it. I think `CClientDC dc (this);` is the same thing as `CClientDC dc = CClientDC(this);`. Or in other words, the former is a simple form.

thanks very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CClientDC dc = CClientDC(this);
```

is equivalent to

```
CClientDC dc(CClientDC(this));
```

For this, `CClientDC` must have a copy or move constructor because you are basically constructing `dc` by copying from a temporary object.

> If the initialization is [...] copy-initialization where the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as [...] the destination, constructors are considered. [...] The constructor so selected is called to initialize the object, with the initializer expression or expression-list as its argument(s). If no constructor applies, or the overload resolution is ambiguous, the initialization is ill-formed.

Answer (score 1):

The copy constructor and overloaded assignment operator for CObject (the base class of CClientDC and CDC) are explicitly marked private afx.h

```
private:
    CObject(const CObject& objectSrc);              // no implementation
    void operator=(const CObject& objectSrc);       // no implementation
```

This is explicitly done because many of the members (such as the HDC member) in the DC objects (and other CObject based classes) would need explicit handling for being referenced multiple times.  Otherwise, the destructor of one instance will likely "close" the underlying handle. Thereby leaving the other instance in an indeterminate (bad) state.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, the OP is not trying to copy `CClientDC` objects. sftrabbit's answer explains why the code doesn't mean what the OP thinks it does.

Answer (score 0):

Inorder for success execution of CClientDC dc = CClientDC(this), there needs to be a overloaded constructor of CClientDC which takes cwind* as parameter and returns CClientDC .
But it does't exists. So the compiler is giving error.

Comment: That constructor does exist, and is explicitly mentioned in the question.